# postgresql does not build with cc flags -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing

Tags: linux, build, gnu-make, postgresql-9.3, gcc4

I'm trying to build Postgresql9.3.9 on Linux box with GCC version 4.4.7 installed.
The configuration part is going smoothly with command:

```
./configure --prefix=/apps/php/postgresql-9.3.9 --enable-thread-safety --without-readline --without-zlib --enable-nls
```

But gmake part ends with:

> gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I../../../src/include -I/apps/php/gd-devel-2.1/include -D_GNU_SOURCE  -DVAL_CONFIGURE="\"'--prefix=/apps/php/postgresql-9.3.9' '--enable-thread-safety' '--without-readline' '--without-zlib' '--enable-nls' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/apps/php/gd-devel-2.1/include'\"" -DVAL_CC="\"gcc\"" -DVAL_CPPFLAGS="\"-I/apps/php/gd-devel-2.1/include -D_GNU_SOURCE\"" -DVAL_CFLAGS="\"-O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv\"" -DVAL_CFLAGS_SL="\"-fpic\"" -DVAL_LDFLAGS="\"-L../../../src/common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-rpath,'/apps/php/postgresql-9.3.9/lib',--enable-new-dtags\"" -DVAL_LDFLAGS_EX="\"\"" -DVAL_LDFLAGS_SL="\"\"" -DVAL_LIBS="\"-lpgport -lpgcommon -lcrypt -ldl -lm \""  -c -o pg_config.o pg_config.c
>   gcc.orig: '--enable-thread-safety': No such file or directory
>   gcc.orig: '--without-readline': No such file or directory
>   gcc.orig: '--without-zlib': No such file or directory
>   gcc.orig: '--enable-nls': No such file or directory
>   gcc.orig: 'CFLAGS=-O2: No such file or directory
>   gcc.orig: 'CPPFLAGS=-I/apps/php/gd-devel-2.1/include'": No such file or directory
>   gcc.orig: ": No such file or directory
>   cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fno-strict-aliasing'"
>   cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fwrapv""
>   gmake[3]:    [pg_config.o] Error 1
>   gmake[3]: Leaving directory /apps/php/postgresql-9.3.9/src/bin/pg_config'
>   gmake[2]:    [all-pg_config-recurse] Error 2
>   gmake[2]: Leaving directory /apps/php/postgresql-9.3.9/src/bin'
>   gmake[1]:    [all-bin-recurse] Error 2
>   gmake[1]: Leaving directory /apps/php/postgresql-9.3.9/src'
>   gmake:       [all-src-recurse] Error 2

Comment: Looks like there is a missing space between `-DVAL_CONFIGURE="\"` and `'--prefix`, and maybe more errors related to all the quoting that's going on in their command, leading to GCC (not its fault) not receiving options in the intended way. Did you take this up with the PostgreSQL devs? I'd also tell them that their continuing reliance on `fno-strict-aliasing` and `fwrapv` makes me less keen to use the program.... but hey, I'm just the peanut gallery. Having said that... using a version of GCC from 2012 is kinda asking for trouble, so maybe that's part of the problem.